# nuxt-color-mode not running. Returning undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Installed [`nuxt-color-mode`](https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/) following their official Docs. Though, when loading the page I'm getting **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')**

`npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/color-mode`

Added to `nuxt.config.js`

```js
buildModules: [
  // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
  '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  '@nuxtjs/color-mode'
],
```

Then within `index.vue` I've added:

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage',
  colorMode: 'light',
}
</script>
```

Unsure why the following line is causing an error:
`<h1>Color mode: {{ $colorMode.value }}</h1>` it's also not adding a class to the `<html>` element.

Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: Hi, you're using Nuxt2 or 3 here?

Comment: `"nuxt": "^2.15.8",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to downgrade to the latest v2 of the package aka `"@nuxtjs/color-mode": "^2.1.1"`. It looks like the v3 is not properly working with Nuxt2.

---

The following template works well

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Color mode: {{ $colorMode.value }}</h1>
    <select v-model="$colorMode.preference">
      <option value="system">System</option>
      <option value="light">Light</option>
      <option value="dark">Dark</option>
      <option value="sepia">Sepia</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.dark-mode body {
  background-color: #091a28;
  color: #ebf4f1;
}
.sepia-mode body {
  background-color: #f1e7d0;
  color: #433422;
}
</style>
```

With

```js
buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/color-mode']
```

and `ssr: true` in `nuxt.config.js`.